# should I avoid testing conditions inside the query mapper in mybatis?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, unit-testing, mybatis

I was told today that the correct thing to do is to not create parameterized mappers like below, but instead to have separate queries for each mapper function. Basically to not test for null or other conditions to create a different query.

I was also told that if I alter the query that is run based on parameters such as startIdx and broadcastOnly below, then I cannot test that logic using unit tests.

I would have to do integration tests of which we have none.

Therefore I was told that is preferable to move all this logic into the service layer. However, if I'm running a different query based on service logic and don't have such logical statements in the mybatis code, then I would need to have many, many functions, calling the appropriate one in the right situation.

Should I really be removing these conditions from the queries and making a separate call to a different function each time based on service logic?

is having these conditions inside the mapper considered having business logic in the database layer? I wasn't sure if people meant the database's switch statements when they talk of business logic in the database layer or whether they include the mapper inside the definition of "database layer".

I want to learn to do things correctly, but I'm used to having an ORM handle things for me.  they seem to think that having logic in the query's generation will result in hard to maintain and impossible to unit test code. I'm a flexible person and want to improve, so please give me some advice

```
<select id="getNotificationsListSize" resultType="long">
        select count(*)
        from notification n
        join notification_box nb on notification_idx = n.idx
        where
        n.status = 'ACTIVE'
        <if test="startDate != null">
            and nb.received_date >= #{startDate}
        </if>
        <choose>
            <when test="broadcastOnly">
                and (nb.account_idx = -1)
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                and (nb.account_idx = -1 or nb.account_idx = #{accountId})
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <if test="useStartIdx">
            and nb.idx >= #{startIdx}
        </if>
    </select>
```

Comment: I think the combination of the two is the best thing, for example if you want to have `mapper.getNotificationListSize(startDate)` and `mapper.getNotificationListSize(startIdx)` then it makes no difference if you have the tests in the XML, as it's the only way to keep mapper names the same.  I'm not particularly a fan of `mapper.getNotificationListSizeByStartDate()` and `mapper.getNotificationListSizeByStartIndex()` and having to write the same query with different where clause.  The former is still as unit testable since you'd be mocking the mapper anyhow to return nothing, value or exception.

Comment: I don't think you should. You should have tests, though. Other than the traditional end-to-end integration tests, it's good to have a way to test each mapper statement independently with DB interaction. The actual implementation may depend on your setup, but check out [mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test](http://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/) if you use spring-boot.